# ZXing objective c example

Tags: iphone, objective-c, zxing

where i can found some good examples / tutorials about the usage ZXing (reader Qrcode) (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) library on iphone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the source, it has an iPhone example called **ScanTest** which includes the ZXingWidget just like you would in your own project. The readme inside there also goes over linkages etc. and what to do if you get certain errors.

https://github.com/zxing/zxing